# Pandas column formatting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column with strings in the form of: `'0.47±0.1'`.
What would be the best way of summing the entire column with an overall uncertainty?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest to create two new columns 'value' & 'error' from your string and thereafter apply the new uncertainty to another new column 'error_tot'. That why it makes all changes obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, seems like the best way to proceed. Have you got an idea as to how efficiently loop through each value and add to val and error columns?

Comment: please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The most straigt forward way is to use `pandas.DataFrame.apply(...,axis=1)` to apply a function across your rows of the tables.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'msr':['1.82±0.10','1.72±.8','1.93±.7']})

def fun(row):
    v,e = row['msr'].split('±')
    row['val'] = float(v)
    row['err'] = float(e)
    return row
df = df.apply(fun,axis=1)

#adding a new systematic uncertainty in quadrature
syst_err = 0.05 
df['tot_err'] = np.sqrt(df['err']**2 + syst_err**2)
```

[image]

Efficiency-wise it is (always) better to not specify a function yourself but use in-built functions. Such as `pandas.DataFrame.str.split()`.

```
val, err = np.array(df['msr'].str.split('±').to_list(),dtype=float).transpose()
df['val'] = val
df['err'] = err
```

A quick run-time comparison gives `2.75 ms ± 134 µs` for the first approach and `425 µs ± 5.35 µs` for the second approach.